# How to retrieve row and column data from table represented by div tags

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath, uiview

I am looking to retrieve data from rows and columns of the table represented by div tags. It is easier when tbody,tr,td tags are present but here the whole table, row and column is represented using div tags (UI grid view). Can someone help how can I proceed with fetching data using selenium webdriver. Any help appreciated.

```
Something like below code:

<div id=table_view>
  <div row = 0>
    <div col =1>
    <div col=2>
  <div row = 1>
    <div col = 1>
    <div col = 2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier as iteration of general table as below :-

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("table_view"));

 //Now find all rows
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@row]"));

for(WebElement row : rows)
{
    List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@col]"));
    for(WebElement col : cols)
    {
        System.out.println(col.getText());
    }
 }
```

Or you can directly iterate all columns only as below :-

```
List<WebElement> cols = driver.findElement(By.id("table_view")).findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@col]"));
 for(WebElement col : cols)
 {
     System.out.println(col.getText());
 }
```

Comment: I tried this way and I get the wrong count of the number of rows. Lets say if I have another div which is not a row but a filler will that be picked up too?

Comment: Did you tried with `.` in xpath means as `By.xpath(".//div[@row]")`??

Comment: I haven't tried with . in xpath but let me try with that and update here.

Comment: So need to try first with provided code as it is and let me know..:)